# Where is "Exclude these categories" settings stored

Tags: nunit

I have searched and searched and cannot find where this is stored. I would like to create a default config that can be used automatically from source control, but cannot figure out where this is saved.

- NUnit gui

  - Categories
  - Exclude these categories

Comment: I did come across that I can start the gui with the /exclude flag. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I finally found it in a [MyTest].VisualState.xml that sits next to the [MyTest].nunit file

```
<SelectedCategories>Integration</SelectedCategories>
<ExcludeCategories>true</ExcludeCategories>
```